# Merging related timeseries data

Tags: javascript, data-structures, highcharts

Given I have two arrays of objects which have the following structure:

```
  {
      avg: 195.6
      max: 195.6
      min: 195.6
      time: 1552448311000
    }
```

Now for an example: The first array has data for a temperature sensor, and the second array has data for a specific engine load. To plot this data, I need the data to be basically in the following format for each point I draw: [load, temperature], so it's a temperature vs load chart.

How can I join these two arrays so that only the points where there is a matching timestamp (a pair) are taken into consideration? The idea is that I could do something like this in the end with one combined array:

```
mergedArray.map(x => [x.load, x.avg])
```

The data can have differences in the amount of data, e.g there can be a lot more temperature points than load points, so I would need to filter the temperature data first to only include the points where there is a matching timestamp point in the load series.

Example of data:

```
const temperatureData = [
  {
    avg: 195.6,
    max: 195.6,
    min: 195.6,
    time: '1.1.2019'
  },
  {
    avg: 300,
    max: 300,
    min: 300,
    time: '1.2.2019'
  }
]

const loadData = [
  {
    avg: 195.6,
    max: 195.6,
    min: 195.6,
    time: '1.1.2019'
  }
]

const expected = [{
  avg: 195.6,
  max: 195.6,
  min: 195.6,
  time: '1.1.2019',
  load: 195.6
}]
```

so only the first temperature data was taken because it has a matching timestamp in the load data.

One pretty bay (?) way to do this would be below, any feedback?

```
    // First filter the load by set load filter
    const filteredLoad = load.filter(x => x.avg >= this.props.filter);

    // Collect the timestamps of the filtered load
    const loadTimeStamps = filteredLoad.map(x => x.time);

    const filteredTemperatures = temperaturData.filter(x => loadTimeStamps.includes(x.time))
    .map ((c, i) => {

      if (!filteredLoad[i]) return null;

      return {
        ...c,
        load: filteredLoad[i].avg
      }
    })
```

Comment: Can you say input and output expected?

Comment: @Hongarc I added a simple example

Comment: A bit off topic for your question, but what are you trying to achieve in highcharts, something like this: https://www.highcharts.com/demo/synchronized-charts ? Or are you trying to make the tooltip have all the relevant infromation. I think it could be easier (and less resource intensive) to play with the plot instead of merging this kind of data before. I could of course be wrong.

Comment: @ewolden yes, that is one possibility also. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You can use loops to filter and merge the data:

```
var newData = [];

for (var i = 0; i < temperatureData.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < loadData.length; j++) {
        if (temperatureData[i].time === loadData[j].time) {
            newData.push(temperatureData[i]);
            newData[newData.length - 1].load = loadData[j].avg
            j = loadData.length;
        }
    }
}
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/9xsdqwct/